# Access files built as "content" during unit test execution with dotCover

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, dotcover

I am using [JetBrains DotCover](http://www.jetbrains.com/dotcover/) to execute and get code coverage for my tests and code.

My project has some files set to build as "Content". These are used from the test like so:

```
// Get executing assembly dir.
var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

// Combine to get the full path to test page.
var page = Path.Combine(dir, @"Pages\Page.htm");

// Open web page.
manager.OpenBrowser(page);
```

Unfortunately, when executing this test using dotCover, *Page.htm* is not copied to the assembly's location.

Is there any way to get the content into the test execution dir, or overcome this and get access to that file in some other way?

Answer (score 1):

That might be a side-effect of shadow copying. "Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location" in this case will give a path to the shadow-copied assembly. 
Try using "Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase" instead.